# Check if a user is already following, then change button text to unfollow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

I have finally made it so that users can follow and unfollow each other in react, now the only obstacle I am left with is changing the button accordingly. This is the basic structure of my API:

```
{
    "id":4,
    "user": {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "sammy"
    },
    "full_name": "Sam Iyke",
    "bio": "Software Enginner",
    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/user_images/ins-gallery_5.jpg",
  
    "followers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "destiny",
            "email": "desphixs@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "username": "jenny",
          "email": "jenny@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "date": "2023-02-16T00:41:46.147589Z"
}
```

I have a followers field there, that have an array of users that are following me, how do i check if the logged in user is in the array, then change thier button to Unfollow, else the button would be Follow.

I am getting the logged in user_id from localstorage jwt

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('authTokens');
const decoded = jwtDecode(token);
const user_id = decoded.user_id;
```

These are the button

```
<div onClick={follow} className="follow-btn color2-bg">
  Follow <i className="fas fa-user-plus" />
</div>
<div onClick={unfollow} className="follow-btn color2-bg bg-danger">
  Unfollow <i className="fas fa-user-minus text-white" />
</div>
```

This is how my useState looks like

```
const [ profile, setProfile ] = useState({
    user: '',
    full_name:"",
    ...
    followers:"",
});
```

So if I want to get the full_name of the user that we are viewing their profile, I do `profile.full_name`

I would provide any more information or detail needed.

## Edit

This is how i add the values to the localstorage

```
 // this saves the user followers to the localstorage
const response = await api.get(baseUrl + '/service-provider/' + profile_ID + '/')
localStorage.setItem("followers", JSON.stringify(response.data.followers))
```

```
function followToggle (){
 if(isFollowing){
    //remove follower
    const followers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("followers"))
    let remaining = followers.filter(user=>user.id!==user_id);
    localStorage.setItem("remaining" ,JSON.stringify(remaining))
    setIsFollowing(false)
}
else{
    //add follower
    const followers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("followers"))
    followers.push(user_id);
    localStorage.setItem("followers" ,JSON.stringify(followers))
    setIsFollowing(true)
 }
}
```

How to make the Text **(Follow or Unfollow)** retained after page refreshes?

Comment: normally you want to check by id, not full name. but not sure why you have 2 different users with the same id in your data.

Comment: This is first user with `id=2` is the owner of the profile and that is thier user_id, the other users with id 1 and 2 are the people following the main user, so for example, is the follower with id 1 is logged in, i want to check if thier id exisits in the followers then, then change thier button to unfollow, i don't know if you understand?

Comment: I still think you want to match by id, not username. You should be storing user_id in the followers data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you can create another `state` to know the user is following him or not, or can do it manually

```
let userIndex= profile.followers.findIndex(i=>i.id===currentUserId)
const [isFollowing,setIsFollowing]=useState(userIndex > -1);
```

then in your code

```
{!isFollowing ? <div onClick={followToggle} className="follow-btn color2-bg">
  Follow <i className="fas fa-user-plus" />
</div>
:<div onClick={followToggle} className="follow-btn color2-bg bg-danger">
  Unfollow <i className="fas fa-user-minus text-white" />
</div>
}
```

then your function wil be like this

```
function followToggle (){
 if(isFollowing){
//remove follower
let followers = //from local storage it should be an array 
let remaining = followers.filter(user=>user.id!==currentUserId);
//set remaining to local storage
}
else{
//add follower
let followers = //from local storage it should be an array 
 followers.push(currentUser);
//set followers to local storage
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, i am getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: profile.followers.findIndex is not a function`

Comment: I have done as you showed above, but the link text does not change when i git the follow or unfollow button, is there something that i am missing?

Comment: which link text?

Comment: the Unfollow and Follow text in the button, not link (my bad), when i remove the `!isFollowing` is changes the button to Unfollow, but this does not change after i click?

Comment: yes you need to change the isFollowing state in followToggle method

Comment: Alright i have updated the setIsFollowing state, but when i refresh the page, the button changes back, it does not retain either Unfollow or follow text, do i need to do something with the local storage to fix this? please help me out here?

Comment: oh I forgot that you are using localStorage, Yes you need to update your localstoreate data every time you follow or unfollow to save changes

Comment: please how do i do this with local storage, i tried doing it but cannot get it to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252113/discussion-between-destiny-franks-and-nazir-hussain).

Comment: I have added the followers and remaining  to localstorage and they get saved now, but i don't get how this would make the follow or unfollow button permanent. I have updated the question with the new codes